# CodeIgniter support for AJAX, and ORM

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was searching for a good php framework for my next project, and I found that CodeIgniter is suitable, but I read this somewhere "codeIgniter has No ORM(Object Relational Mapping), No AJAX support", is that right?

Comment: How is it possible to have "no AJAX support"? It's like saying there's no CSS support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "codeIgniter has No ORM(Object Relational Mapping)

TRUE. But it has a nice and handy custom [**Active Record class**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) which acts as an ORM, supporting many database drivers; as of 2.0.3, supported databases are mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8.

And, if you want, you can just add your favourite ORM to the libraries or drivers and you can use that instead. There are many tutorials out there and answers on SO if you're stuck with this procedure, though it's pretty easy and the manual is really clear on how to create/use custom libraries.

> No AJAX support

Whatever this means, it's not true. CI is a php framework for web development, so write your javascript ajax code inside views, call the right controller's method, and AJAX will work just fine.

If you mean there's no native support for that, i.e. using native classes to the task, then it's partly right. CI has the [**javascript**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html) class which is a loader/helper for jQuery; I never used it since I prefer loading that framework by myself and working directly on that, but you might give it a try.

Comment: From personal experience, just writing your own JS / AJAX code in the view works perfectly fine.

Comment: The Javascript class is the first thing I delete from a new copy of CI - it could have been useful (like magic JS form validation) but it only serves as another (useless) layer of abstraction on top of the already elegant jQuery. "write your javascript ajax code inside views"... How about in javascript file?

Comment: LOL, I know, in fact I had to check on the site if it was really there or not, never even considered. But, who knows, maybe OP's looking for something like that by "AJAX support".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `CI has no built-in ORM`. but it supports different `libraires and classes` which acts as `ORM`.
for example:

[doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [data mapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)

can be used along with codeigniter to fulfill your requirements.

as far as `CI support for AJAX` is concerned, AJAX works perfectly fine with `codeigniter`. Do keep in mind when `developing using Ajax`, that if someone turns off `Javascript` in their browser, what you develop will not work.

Hope this helps.